# Validating subdomain of url globally

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

Want to check current subdomain in url is valid or not. I'm able to validate if current url has subdomain or not. I want to make an api call from angular to backend with subdomain name and check if its valid. Where will be the best place in angular to do this? app.run ? some factory ?

If valid then only it should display site contents, otherwise redirect to unauthorized page. I also needs to check the current session cookies if they are valid for current subdomain. I guess I can do this by creating cookie for that subdomain only and not global domain cookie, right?

Comment: $http.get('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    success get data;
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   $location.path("/unauthrozied.html");
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });

Comment: y dont you perfer this

Comment: @PavanAsTechie I know how to make http calls to backend server, my question is where should I have the call to backend to validate subdomain?

Comment: Sorry for my argument. There is error function which will redirects to unauthroized.html, i think angular validates if success return result else fail and show the result  404

Comment: it is better to do in factory or service all the api call goes in to service or factory